# Access 2007: Problems creating multi page report

Tags: ms-access-2007

I am designing a report that shows product id, description and then quantities and dollar values for 7 different regions plus total quantity and total dollars for each product row) and also sums every column (all the quantities and dollar values). This report gets exported to a .rtf file and then emailed to various people. My current setup has the report being 22-inches wide. In Access, it shows up perfectly in Report View (product id, description, and regions 1-4 quantities and dollars on one page and regions 5-7 plus the total section on the other). When it exports it to a .rtf, it doesn't show the second page (unless you are in draft mode in Word).

I am looking for an easy way or some type of direction to have everything display correctly when exported. I've been playing around with layout, spacing, and page breaks but it either ends up displaying each individual product on separate pages or takes an enormous amount of time to load the formatted page (which doesn't work for my user). I have also tried using a subreport but get the same results as what I was doing with the page breaks.

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there is a problem when I have something like report package (multiple page report.) What I did with my situation is I spit to one page report. Say Region 1-7, I have 7 reports. And use Loop to run, save, or pint it all. You may end up with 7 rtf file to email.

Other option is using MailMerge. You can do all the report in MS Words instead of in Access report. So you create say, 7-page template for all regions and added MailMerge fields in it. Then run it.

hope this help.